# use first row data as column names in r

Tags: r, names

I have a dirty dataset that I could not read it with `header = T`. After I read and clean it, I would like to use the now first row data as the column name. I tried multiple methods on Stack Overflow without success. What could be the problem?

The dataset `t1` should look like this after clean up:

```
      V1    V2  V3  V4  V5
1   col1    col2    col3    col4
2   row1    2   4   5   56
3   row2    74  74  3   534
4   row3    865 768 8   7
5   row4    68  86  65  87
```

- I tried: `colnames(t1) <- t1[1,]`. Nothing happens.
- I tried: `names(t1) <- ti[1,]`, Nothing happens.
- I tried: `lapply(t1, function(x) {names(x) <- x[1, ]; x})`. It returns an error message:

  ```
  Error in `[.default`(x, 1, ) : incorrect number of dimensions
  ```

Could anyone help?

Comment: Looking at your data, do you have blanks in some columns? try str(t1[1,]) and see if it's doing what you expect.

Comment: Could you paste in the first few lines of the file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Row to colnames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44031720/row-to-colnames)

Comment: Is there a way to do this using `rename_all` from dplyr

Comment: `colnames(t1) <- t1[1, ]` and then `t1 <- t1[-1, ]` should work

Answer (score 70):

Sam Firke's ever useful package [`janitor`](https://github.com/sfirke/janitor) has a function especially for this: `row_to_names`.

Example from his documentation:

```
library(janitor)

x <- data.frame(X_1 = c(NA, "Title", 1:3),
           X_2 = c(NA, "Title2", 4:6))
x %>%
  row_to_names(row_number = 2)
```

Answer (score 28):

```
header.true <- function(df) {
  names(df) <- as.character(unlist(df[1,]))
  df[-1,]
}
```

**Test**

```
df1 <- data.frame(c("a", 1,2,3), c("b", 4,5,6))
header.true(df1)
  a b
2 1 4
3 2 5
4 3 6
```

Comment: life saver little fucntion ..every time i have to see the V1 issues not sure why

Answer (score 16):

Probably, the data type of the data frame columns are factors. That is why the code you tried didn't work, you can check it using `str(df)`:

First option

> Use the argument `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`when you import your data:

```
df <- read.table(text =  "V1    V2  V3  V4  V5
                        col1    col2    col3    col4 col5
                        row1    2   4   5   56
                        row2    74  74  3   534
                        row3    865 768 8   7
                        row4    68  86  65  87", header = TRUE, 
                        stringsAsFactors = FALSE )
```

Then you can use your first attempt, then remove your first row if you'd like:

```
colnames(df) <- df[1,]
df <- df[-1, ]
```

Second option

It will work if your columns are factors or characters:

```
names(df) <- lapply(df[1, ], as.character)
df <- df[-1,]
```

Output:

```
  col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
2 row1    2    4    5   56
3 row2   74   74    3  534
4 row3  865  768    8    7
5 row4   68   86   65   87
```

Comment: Not sure if relevant, but I had a matrix, and this solution almost worked except I changed names(df) to colnames(df), and it seems to have worked?

Answer (score 12):

While @sbha has already offered a `tidyverse` solution, I would like to leave a fully pipeable `dplyr` option. I agree that this should could be an incredibly useful function.

```
library(dplyr)
data.frame(x = c("a", 1, 2, 3), y = c("b", 4, 5, 6)) %>%
  `colnames<-`(.[1, ]) %>%
  .[-1, ]
```

Answer (score 6):

How about:

```
my.names <- t1[1,]

colnames(t1) <- my.names
```

i.e. specifically naming the row as a variable?

with the following code:

```
namex <-c("col1","col2","col3","col4")
row1 <- c(2, 4, 5, 56)
row2 <- c(74, 73, 3, 534)
row3 <- c(865, 768, 8, 7)
row4 <- c(68, 58, 65, 87)

t1 <- data.frame(namex, row1, row2, row3, row4)
t1 <- t(t1)

my.names <- t1[1,]

colnames(t1) <- my.names
```

It seems to work, but maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: yes you are missing two steps, first you need to remove the first row which you are using as column names and convert the `matrix` to `data.frame`

Answer (score 6):

You almost did that, only missed calling a vector with c

```
colnames(t1)=t1[c(1),]
```

Then you can erase the first row, as now it is doubled

```
t1=t1[-c(1),]
```

Comment: best solution ever!

Answer (score 5):

Take a step back, when you read your data use `skip=1` in `read.table` to miss out the first line entirely. This *should* make life a bit easier when you're cleaning data, particularly for data type. This is key as your problem stems from your data being encoded as factor.

You can then read in your column names separately with `nrows=1` in `read.table`.

Answer (score 3):

Similar to some of the other answers, here is a `dplyr`/`tidyverse` option:

```
library(tidyverse)

names(df) <- df %>% slice(1) %>% unlist()
df <- df %>% slice(-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using data.table:

```
library(data.table)

namex <-c("col1","col2","col3","col4")
row1 <- c(2, 4, 5, 56)
row2 <- c(74, 73, 3, 534)
row3 <- c(865, 768, 8, 7)
row4 <- c(68, 58, 65, 87)

t1 <- data.table(namex, row1, row2, row3, row4)
t1 <- data.table(t(t1))

setnames(t1, as.character(t1[1,]))
t1 <- t1[-1,]
```

Answer (score 0):

Building off of Pierre L's answer. Sometimes the first row in a document ends up getting split into two or more rows when pulled into a data frame. This slight modification helped solve that for me.

```
header.true <- function(df) {
  r1 <- as.character(unlist(df[1,]))
  r2 <- as.character(unlist(df[2,]))
  r1.2 <- paste(r1,r2, sep = ".")
  names(df) <- r1.2
  df[-c(1,2),]
}
```

**Test**

```
df1 <- data.frame(c("a", "xx",1,2,3), c("b", "xx",4,5,6))
header.true(df1)
  a.xx b.xx
3    1    4
4    2    5
5    3    6
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the shortest way is:

```
colnames(df) <- unlist(df[1, ])
```