# Convert data frame row to column names

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse, tibble

Is there a quick way (part of the `tidyverse` API perhaps) to turn a row into column names for a `data.frame` or `tibble`, somewhat similar to `tibble::column_to_rownames`?

I realize there are many ways to do this, e.g. somewhat clumsily:

```
> df <- head(iris)
> 
> df %>%
+     set_colnames(magrittr::extract(., 1,)) %>%
+     magrittr::extract(-1,)
  5.1 3.5 1.4 0.2      1
2 4.9 3.0 1.4 0.2 setosa
3 4.7 3.2 1.3 0.2 setosa
4 4.6 3.1 1.5 0.2 setosa
5 5.0 3.6 1.4 0.2 setosa
6 5.4 3.9 1.7 0.4 setosa
```

Comment: Use `header = T` when importing your data. Use `skip` as necessary to make the header the first line.

Comment: In my case, the data isn't being read from file, but that would work if it were

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[`janitor::row_to_names()`](https://sfirke.github.io/janitor/reference/row_to_names.html) implements this:

```r
library(tidyverse)

iris %>%
  head() %>%
  janitor::row_to_names(1)
#>   5.1 3.5 1.4 0.2      1
#> 2 4.9 3.0 1.4 0.2 setosa
#> 3 4.7 3.2 1.3 0.2 setosa
#> 4 4.6 3.1 1.5 0.2 setosa
#> 5 5.0 3.6 1.4 0.2 setosa
#> 6 5.4 3.9 1.7 0.4 setosa
```

<sup>Created on 2019-05-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 13):

Well, you can simply: `colnames(df) <- as.character(df[1, ])`

And if you want to remove this first row: `df <- df[-1,]`