# Split and recombine data: Is there an efficient way to do this

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, data-cleaning, tidy

I have a very large dataset that i measured on an instrument with repeated, unequal headers. i'm trying to first subset every two rows i.e header and data then recombine using `bind_row()` from the tidyverse package. I've looked at the questions like [use-first-row-data-as-column-names-in-r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32054368/use-first-row-data-as-column-names-in-r) and its totally different from what i want to do.

here is a dput of my  sample data

```
structure(list(X1 = c("File #", "76", "File #", "77", "File #", 
"78", "File #", "79", "File #", "80"), X2 = c("DateTime", "3/8/2020 18:08", 
"DateTime", "3/8/20 18:08", "DateTime", "3/8/2020 18:08", "DateTime", 
"3/8/2020 18:08", "DateTime", "3/8/2020 18:08"), X3 = c("Operator", 
"Supervisor", "Operator", "Supervisor", "Operator", "Supervisor", 
"Operator", "Supervisor", "Operator", "Supervisor"), X4 = c("Name", 
NA, "Name", NA, "Name", NA, "Name", NA, "Name", NA), X5 = c("ID", 
"0", "ID", "0", "ID", "0", "ID", "0", "ID", "0"), X6 = c("Sample", 
"Local 2", "Sample", "Local 2", "Sample", "Local 2", "Sample", 
"Local 2", "Sample", "Local 2"), X7 = c("Project", "XRF DATA", 
"Project", "XRF DATA", "Project", "XRF DATA", "Project", "XRF DATA", 
"Project", "XRF DATA"), X8 = c("Application", "GeoExploration", 
"Application", "GeoExploration", "Application", "GeoExploration", 
"Application", "GeoExploration", "Application", "GeoExploration"
), X9 = c("Method", "Oxide3phase", "Method", "Oxide3phase", "Method", 
"Oxide3phase", "Method", "Oxide3phase", "Method", "Oxide3phase"
), X10 = c("ElapsedTime", "0", "ElapsedTime", "0", "ElapsedTime", 
"0", "ElapsedTime", "0", "ElapsedTime", "0"), X11 = c("Alloy 1", 
NA, "Alloy 1", NA, "Alloy 1", NA, "Alloy 1", NA, "Alloy 1", NA
), X12 = c("Match Qual 1", "0", "Match Qual 1", "0", "Match Qual 1", 
"0", "Match Qual 1", "0", "Match Qual 1", "0"), X13 = c("Alloy 2", 
NA, "Alloy 2", NA, "Alloy 2", NA, "Alloy 2", NA, "Alloy 2", NA
), X14 = c("Match Qual 2", "0", "Match Qual 2", "0", "Match Qual 2", 
"0", "Match Qual 2", "0", "Match Qual 2", "0"), X15 = c("Alloy 3", 
NA, "Alloy 3", NA, "Alloy 3", NA, "Alloy 3", NA, "Alloy 3", NA
), X16 = c("Match Qual 3", "0", "Match Qual 3", "0", "Match Qual 3", 
"0", "Match Qual 3", "0", "Match Qual 3", "0"), X17 = c("MgO", 
"0.6579", "MgO", "0.6579", "MgO", "0.6579", "MgO", "0.6579", 
"MgO", "0.6579"), X18 = c("MgO Err", "0.7778", "MgO Err", "0.7778", 
"MgO Err", "0.7778", "MgO Err", "0.7778", "MgO Err", "0.7778"
), X19 = c("Al2O3", "11.1503", "Al2O3", "11.1503", "Al2O3", "11.1503", 
"Al2O3", "11.1503", "Al2O3", "11.1503"), X20 = c("Al2O3 Err", 
"0.5363", "Al2O3 Err", "0.5363", "Al2O3 Err", "0.5363", "Al2O3 Err", 
"0.5363", "Al2O3 Err", "0.5363"), X21 = c("SiO2", "67.523", "SiO2", 
"67.523", "SiO2", "67.523", "SiO2", "67.523", "SiO2", "67.523"
), X22 = c("SiO2 Err", "0.8529", "SiO2 Err", "0.8529", "SiO2 Err", 
"0.8529", "SiO2 Err", "0.8529", "SiO2 Err", "0.8529"), X23 = c("P", 
"0.0035", "P", "0.0035", "P", "0.0035", "P", "0.0035", "P", "0.0035"
), X24 = c("P Err", "0.0177", "P Err", "0.0177", "P Err", "0.0177", 
"P Err", "0.0177", "P Err", "0.0177"), X25 = c("S", "0.11", "S", 
"0.11", "S", "0.11", "S", "0.11", "S", "0.11"), X26 = c("S Err", 
"0.0195", "S Err", "0.0195", "S Err", "0.0195", "S Err", "0.0195", 
"S Err", "0.0195"), X27 = c("Cl", "0", "Cl", "0", "Cl", "0", 
"Cl", "0", "Cl", "0"), X28 = c("Cl Err", "0.0213", "Cl Err", 
"0.0213", "Cl Err", "0.0213", "Cl Err", "0.0213", "Cl Err", "0.0213"
), X29 = c("K2O", "4.6562", "K2O", "4.6562", "K2O", "4.6562", 
"K2O", "4.6562", "K2O", "4.6562"), X30 = c("K2O Err", "0.0516", 
"K2O Err", "0.0516", "K2O Err", "0.0516", "K2O Err", "0.0516", 
"K2O Err", "0.0516"), X31 = c("Ca", "0.6011", "Ca", "0.6011", 
"Ca", "0.6011", "Ca", "0.6011", "Ca", "0.6011"), X32 = c("Ca Err", 
"0.0136", "Ca Err", "0.0136", "Ca Err", "0.0136", "Ca Err", "0.0136", 
"Ca Err", "0.0136"), X33 = c("Ti", "0.1598", "Ti", "0.1598", 
"Ti", "0.1598", "Ti", "0.1598", "Ti", "0.1598"), X34 = c("Ti Err", 
"0.0177", "Ti Err", "0.0177", "Ti Err", "0.0177", "Ti Err", "0.0177", 
"Ti Err", "0.0177"), X35 = c("V", "0.0064", "V", "0.0064", "V", 
"0.0064", "V", "0.0064", "V", "0.0064"), X36 = c("V Err", "0.0088", 
"V Err", "0.0088", "V Err", "0.0088", "V Err", "0.0088", "V Err", 
"0.0088"), X37 = c("Cr", "0.0042", "Cr", "0.0042", "Cr", "0.0042", 
"Cr", "0.0042", "Cr", "0.0042"), X38 = c("Cr Err", "0.0033", 
"Cr Err", "0.0033", "Cr Err", "0.0033", "Cr Err", "0.0033", "Cr Err", 
"0.0033"), X39 = c("Mn", "0.0976", "Mn", "0.0976", "Mn", "0.0976", 
"Mn", "0.0976", "Mn", "0.0976"), X40 = c("Mn Err", "0.0063", 
"Mn Err", "0.0063", "Mn Err", "0.0063", "Mn Err", "0.0063", "Mn Err", 
"0.0063"), X41 = c("Fe", "1.5828", "Fe", "1.5828", "Fe", "1.5828", 
"Fe", "1.5828", "Fe", "1.5828"), X42 = c("Fe Err", "0.0186", 
"Fe Err", "0.0186", "Fe Err", "0.0186", "Fe Err", "0.0186", "Fe Err", 
"0.0186"), X43 = c("Co", "0.0042", "Co", "0.0042", "Co", "0.0042", 
"Co", "0.0042", "Co", "0.0042"), X44 = c("Co Err", "0.0032", 
"Co Err", "0.0032", "Co Err", "0.0032", "Co Err", "0.0032", "Co Err", 
"0.0032"), X45 = c("Ni", "0.0052", "Ni", "0.0052", "Ni", "0.0052", 
"Ni", "0.0052", "Ni", "0.0052"), X46 = c("Ni Err", "0.0012", 
"Ni Err", "0.0012", "Ni Err", "0.0012", "Ni Err", "0.0012", "Ni Err", 
"0.0012"), X47 = c("Cu", "0.0218", "Cu", "0.0218", "Cu", "0.0218", 
"Cu", "0.0218", "Cu", "0.0218"), X48 = c("Cu Err", "0.0015", 
"Cu Err", "0.0015", "Cu Err", "0.0015", "Cu Err", "0.0015", "Cu Err", 
"0.0015"), X49 = c("Zn", "0.0709", "Zn", "0.0709", "Zn", "0.0709", 
"Zn", "0.0709", "Zn", "0.0709"), X50 = c("Zn Err", "0.0024", 
"Zn Err", "0.0024", "Zn Err", "0.0024", "Zn Err", "0.0024", "Zn Err", 
"0.0024"), X51 = c("Ga", "0.0006", "Ga", "0.0006", "Ga", "0.0006", 
"Ga", "0.0006", "Ga", "0.0006"), X52 = c("Ga Err", "0.0009", 
"Ga Err", "0.0009", "Ga Err", "0.0009", "Ga Err", "0.0009", "Ga Err", 
"0.0009"), X53 = c("As", "0.0041", "As", "0.0041", "As", "0.0041", 
"As", "0.0041", "As", "0.0041"), X54 = c("As Err", "0.0019", 
"As Err", "0.0019", "As Err", "0.0019", "As Err", "0.0019", "As Err", 
"0.0019"), X55 = c("Se", "0.0001", "Se", "0.0001", "Se", "0.0001", 
"Se", "0.0001", "Se", "0.0001"), X56 = c("Se Err", "0.0002", 
"Se Err", "0.0002", "Se Err", "0.0002", "Se Err", "0.0002", "Se Err", 
"0.0002"), X57 = c("Rb", "0.0147", "Rb", "0.0147", "Rb", "0.0147", 
"Rb", "0.0147", "Rb", "0.0147"), X58 = c("Rb Err", "0.0008", 
"Rb Err", "0.0008", "Rb Err", "0.0008", "Rb Err", "0.0008", "Rb Err", 
"0.0008"), X59 = c("Sr", "0.0138", "Sr", "0.0138", "Sr", "0.0138", 
"Sr", "0.0138", "Sr", "0.0138"), X60 = c("Sr Err", "0.0007", 
"Sr Err", "0.0007", "Sr Err", "0.0007", "Sr Err", "0.0007", "Sr Err", 
"0.0007"), X61 = c("Y", "0.0032", "Y", "0.0032", "Y", "0.0032", 
"Y", "0.0032", "Y", "0.0032"), X62 = c("Y Err", "0.0005", "Y Err", 
"0.0005", "Y Err", "0.0005", "Y Err", "0.0005", "Y Err", "0.0005"
), X63 = c("Zr", "0.0277", "Zr", "0.0277", "Zr", "0.0277", "Zr", 
"0.0277", "Zr", "0.0277"), X64 = c("Zr Err", "0.0011", "Zr Err", 
"0.0011", "Zr Err", "0.0011", "Zr Err", "0.0011", "Zr Err", "0.0011"
), X65 = c("Nb", "0.002", "Nb", "0.002", "Nb", "0.002", "Nb", 
"0.002", "Nb", "0.002"), X66 = c("Nb Err", "0.0005", "Nb Err", 
"0.0005", "Nb Err", "0.0005", "Nb Err", "0.0005", "Nb Err", "0.0005"
), X67 = c("Mo", "0", "Mo", "0", "Mo", "0", "Mo", "0", "Mo", 
"0"), X68 = c("Mo Err", "0.0009", "Mo Err", "0.0009", "Mo Err", 
"0.0009", "Mo Err", "0.0009", "Mo Err", "0.0009"), X69 = c("Cd", 
"0", "Cd", "0", "Cd", "0", "Cd", "0", "Cd", "0"), X70 = c("Cd Err", 
"0.0009", "Cd Err", "0.0009", "Cd Err", "0.0009", "Cd Err", "0.0009", 
"Cd Err", "0.0009"), X71 = c("Sn", "0", "Sn", "0", "Sn", "0", 
"Sn", "0", "Sn", "0"), X72 = c("Sn Err", "0.0054", "Sn Err", 
"0.0054", "Sn Err", "0.0054", "Sn Err", "0.0054", "Sn Err", "0.0054"
), X73 = c("Sb", "0.0144", "Sb", "0.0144", "Sb", "0.0144", "Sb", 
"0.0144", "Sb", "0.0144"), X74 = c("Sb Err", "0.0044", "Sb Err", 
"0.0044", "Sb Err", "0.0044", "Sb Err", "0.0044", "Sb Err", "0.0044"
), X75 = c("Te", "0.0002", "Te", "0.0002", "Te", "0.0002", "Te", 
"0.0002", "Te", "0.0002"), X76 = c("Te Err", "0.0005", "Te Err", 
"0.0005", "Te Err", "0.0005", "Te Err", "0.0005", "Te Err", "0.0005"
), X77 = c("Ba", "0.1185", "Ba", "0.1185", "Ba", "0.1185", "Ba", 
"0.1185", "Ba", "0.1185"), X78 = c("Ba Err", "0.0142", "Ba Err", 
"0.0142", "Ba Err", "0.0142", "Ba Err", "0.0142", "Ba Err", "0.0142"
), X79 = c("La", "0", "La", "0", "La", "0", "La", "0", "La", 
"0"), X80 = c("La Err", "0.0156", "La Err", "0.0156", "La Err", 
"0.0156", "La Err", "0.0156", "La Err", "0.0156"), X81 = c("Ce", 
"0.002", "Ce", "0.002", "Ce", "0.002", "Ce", "0.002", "Ce", "0.002"
), X82 = c("Ce Err", "0.022", "Ce Err", "0.022", "Ce Err", "0.022", 
"Ce Err", "0.022", "Ce Err", "0.022"), X83 = c("Hf", "0", "Hf", 
"0", "Hf", "0", "Hf", "0", "Hf", "0"), X84 = c("Hf Err", "0.0026", 
"Hf Err", "0.0026", "Hf Err", "0.0026", "Hf Err", "0.0026", "Hf Err", 
"0.0026"), X85 = c("Ta", "0", "Ta", "0", "Ta", "0", "Ta", "0", 
"Ta", "0"), X86 = c("Ta Err", "0.0021", "Ta Err", "0.0021", "Ta Err", 
"0.0021", "Ta Err", "0.0021", "Ta Err", "0.0021"), X87 = c("W", 
"0", "W", "0", "W", "0", "W", "0", "W", "0"), X88 = c("W Err", 
"0.0073", "W Err", "0.0073", "W Err", "0.0073", "W Err", "0.0073", 
"W Err", "0.0073"), X89 = c("Pt", "0", "Pt", "0", "Pt", "0", 
"Pt", "0", "Pt", "0"), X90 = c("Pt Err", "0.0014", "Pt Err", 
"0.0014", "Pt Err", "0.0014", "Pt Err", "0.0014", "Pt Err", "0.0014"
), X91 = c("Hg", "0.0002", "Hg", "0.0002", "Bi", "0.0001", "Hg", 
"0.0002", "Hg", "0.0002"), X92 = c("Hg Err", "0.0008", "Hg Err", 
"0.0008", "Bi Err", "0.0012", "Hg Err", "0.0008", "Hg Err", "0.0008"
), X93 = c("Tl", "0", "Tl", "0", "Th", "0.0005", "Tl", "0", "Tl", 
"0"), X94 = c("Tl Err", "0.0023", "Tl Err", "0.0023", "Th Err", 
"0.0012", "Tl Err", "0.0023", "Tl Err", "0.0023"), X95 = c("Pb", 
"0.0834", "Pb", "0.0834", "U", "0", "Pb", "0.0834", "Pb", "0.0834"
), X96 = c("Pb Err", "0.0034", "Pb Err", "0.0034", "U Err", "0.0035", 
"Pb Err", "0.0034", "Pb Err", "0.0034"), X97 = c("Bi", "0.0001", 
"Bi", "0.0001", "Cal Check", "Passed", "Th", "0.0005", "Bi", 
"0.0001"), X98 = c("Bi Err", "0.0012", "Bi Err", "0.0012", NA, 
NA, "Th Err", "0.0012", "Bi Err", "0"), X99 = c("Th", "0.0005", 
"Cal Check", "Passed", NA, NA, "U", "0", "Th", "0.0005"), X100 = c("Th Err", 
"0.0012", NA, NA, NA, NA, "U Err", "0.0035", "Th Err", "0.0012"
), X101 = c("U", "0", NA, NA, NA, NA, "Cal Check", "Passed", 
"U", "0"), X102 = c("U Err", "0.0035", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
"U Err", "0.0035"), X103 = c("Cal Check", "Passed", NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, "Cal Check", "Passed")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

You'll notice each measurement has different number of columns which adds to the complexity... Also, i will like to get rid of any column that ends with "Err" e.g. "Br Err". Kindly note that i've intentionally duplicated values just to be able to have sufficient data to explain my problem.  i was planning to create a function so i tried
 `sample_data <- read_csv("sample_data.csv", col_names = FALSE)`
then

```
df_1<- sample_data%>%slice(1:2)%>%
janitor::row_to_names(1)%>% 
select(-ends_with("Err"))
```

for the first two rows, the preceding rows i.e gave error

> Error: Columns `100`, `101`, `102`, `103` cannot have NA as name

when i tried

```
df_2<- sample_data%>%
slice(3:4)%>%
janitor::row_to_names(1)%>%
 select(-ends_with("Err"))
```

probably due to the way the data was read-in.

What i want at the end is to use `bind_rows() to combine everything

[image]

packages used

```
library(janitor)
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)
library(lubridate)
```

Comment: To be clear, when I look at rows 1 & 2, row 1 is the column names, row 2 is the observations, and the set of column names might be different for different pairs of rows? And you need to bind together the observation rows, which in this example are even-numbered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this fits what you're trying to do. Count off your rows by twos, so each pair represents an observation where row 1 is measures and row 2 is values. Then split.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

by_pair <- dat %>%
  mutate(obvs = ceiling(seq_along(X1) / 2)) %>%
  split(.$obvs)

by_pair[[2]]
#> # A tibble: 2 x 104
#>   X1     X2    X3    X4    X5    X6    X7    X8    X9    X10   X11   X12   X13  
#>   <chr>  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1 File # Date… Oper… Name  ID    Samp… Proj… Appl… Meth… Elap… Allo… Matc… Allo…
#> 2 77     3/8/… Supe… <NA>  0     Loca… XRF … GeoE… Oxid… 0     <NA>  0     <NA> 
# ... truncated
```

I converted the split tibbles back to base `data.frame` objects so that subsetting a single row would get a vector—makes it easier to then subset values based on corresponding names being NA. Drop rows whose measures end in "Err," then make sure every observation has the full set of measures with `complete`, filling in `NA` where that measurement wasn't made. Then reshape back to wide.

```r
by_pair %>%
  map(select, -obvs) %>%
  map(as.data.frame) %>%
  map_dfr(function(df) {
    df_names <- df[1, ]
    df_vals <- df[2, ][!is.na(df_names)]
    tibble(measure = df_names[!is.na(df_names)], value = df_vals)
  }, .id = "obvs") %>%
  filter(!grepl("\\bErr$", measure)) %>%
  mutate(measure = forcats::as_factor(measure)) %>%
  complete(obvs, measure) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = measure)
#> # A tibble: 5 x 61
#>   obvs  `File #` DateTime Operator Name  ID    Sample Project Application Method
#>   <chr> <chr>    <chr>    <chr>    <chr> <chr> <chr>  <chr>   <chr>       <chr> 
#> 1 1     76       3/8/202… Supervi… <NA>  0     Local… XRF DA… GeoExplora… Oxide…
#> 2 2     77       3/8/20 … Supervi… <NA>  0     Local… XRF DA… GeoExplora… Oxide…
#> 3 3     78       3/8/202… Supervi… <NA>  0     Local… XRF DA… GeoExplora… Oxide…
#> 4 4     79       3/8/202… Supervi… <NA>  0     Local… XRF DA… GeoExplora… Oxide…
#> 5 5     80       3/8/202… Supervi… <NA>  0     Local… XRF DA… GeoExplora… Oxide…
#> # … with 51 more variables: ElapsedTime <chr>, `Alloy 1` <chr>, `Match Qual
#> #   1` <chr>, `Alloy 2` <chr>, `Match Qual 2` <chr>, `Alloy 3` <chr>, `Match
#> #   Qual 3` <chr>, MgO <chr>, Al2O3 <chr>, SiO2 <chr>, P <chr>, S <chr>,
#> #   Cl <chr>, K2O <chr>, Ca <chr>, Ti <chr>, V <chr>, Cr <chr>, Mn <chr>,
#> #   Fe <chr>, Co <chr>, Ni <chr>, Cu <chr>, Zn <chr>, Ga <chr>, As <chr>,
#> #   Se <chr>, Rb <chr>, Sr <chr>, Y <chr>, Zr <chr>, Nb <chr>, Mo <chr>,
#> #   Cd <chr>, Sn <chr>, Sb <chr>, Te <chr>, Ba <chr>, La <chr>, Ce <chr>,
#> #   Hf <chr>, Ta <chr>, W <chr>, Pt <chr>, Hg <chr>, Tl <chr>, Pb <chr>,
#> #   Bi <chr>, Th <chr>, U <chr>, `Cal Check` <chr>
```

Comment: i noticed though that all my columns with values are still displayed as character.

Comment: The sample of data you posted is all character columns. After getting the wide-shaped data you can convert columns to numeric or whatever as necessary, but as of right now there isn't anything in your sample or the code here that would have done any conversion

Comment: thanks for the prompt response... i added `type_convert()` after `pivot_wider()` and it solved the problem. You see, read_csv() imports the data (columns) as chr because of the repeated headers. Again, many thanks

Comment: I was wondering if this can be extended to a case where there is a mix of one header - one row of data and some cases one header two-three rows of similar data. Your help is appreciated